# Identity Framework with IOC: "The current type is an interface and cannot be constructed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, unity-container

I had to move all our IdentityFramework classes and interfaces to separate libraries, which meant that the new `Common.Models.Interfaces` interface library can only reference other interface libraries (or .net libs). That mean that all my `ApplicationUser` parameters and variables became `IApplicationUser`.

After several hours of changes I have it all building, but at runtime I get the following error:

> The current type, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[Common.Models.Interfaces.Account.IApplicationUser], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

**So my question is: What type mapping might I be missing?**

I had previously resolved `dbcontext` problems with the following code from http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration (specifically the use of the `InjectionConstructor`)

```
container.RegisterType<IApplicationUser, ApplicationUser>();
container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
container.RegisterType<IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationDbContext>();
container.RegisterType<IIdentityMessageService, EmailService>();
container.RegisterType<IApplicationSignInManager, ApplicationSignInManager>();
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));
```

**Note: Other error mentioned here removed, as it was misleading. It looks like I need additional mappings, but no clue what.**

The app user interface and class are as follows (trimmed), so that you might spot where I have gone wrong:

### IApplicationUser.cs

```
public interface IApplicationUser : IUser, IUser<string>
{
     ...
}
```

### ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IApplicationUser
{
     ...
}
```

### ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

*Obviously it is not possible to include all the related code to repro this, as it runs to 1000s of lines, and a repro should not be needed, so only IOC experts should apply.* :)

### Second attempt:

After a helpful link from `@guillaume31` I tried the following:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IUserStore<>), typeof(UserStore<>), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));
```

This compiles, but I get a new error:

> GenericArguments[0], 'Common.Models.Interfaces.Account.IApplicationUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6[TUser,TRole,TKey,TUserLogin,TUserRole,TUserClaim]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'

### Third attempt

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IUserStore<>), typeof(UserStore<ApplicationUser>), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));
```

Result in this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1[Vero.Common.Verofy.Models.Account.ApplicationUser]' to type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[Vero.Common.Verofy.Models.Interfaces.Account.IApplicationUser]'.

### Fourth attempt

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IUserStore<IApplicationUser>), typeof(UserStore<ApplicationUser>), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));
```

This compiles, but I get this error (same as previous test):

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1[Common.Models.Account.ApplicationUser]' to type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[Common.Models.Interfaces.Account.IApplicationUser]'.

### Fifth attempt (using registered instances):

```
var applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
container.RegisterInstance<DbContext>(applicationDbContext);
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(applicationDbContext);
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IUserStore<IApplicationUser>), userStore);
```

The new error is:

> The type Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1[[Vero.Common.Verofy.Models.Account.ApplicationUser, Vero.Common.Verofy.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] cannot be assigned to variables of type Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[Vero.Common.Verofy.Models.Interfaces.Account.IApplicationUser].
>   Parameter name: instance

### Sixth attempt (bypass injection):

The following simple line also fails at runtime:

```
IUserStore<IApplicationUser> test = (IUserStore<IApplicationUser>)new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(applicationDbContext);
```

The error is:

Unable to cast object of type > 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1[Common.Models.Account.ApplicationUser]' to type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[Common.Models.Interfaces.Account.IApplicationUser]'.

### Summary

All of these problems would indicate I have an incompatibility between my `IUserStore<IApplicationUser>` and my `UserStore<ApplicationUser>` class implementations. Ask for more details of any class you think may help.

### Update

### The basic problem comes down to this dependency:

- Our `ApplicationUser` class needed to expose `public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> manager)`
- This forces the `UserManager` to be of type IApplicationUser and not Application user and cause a large number of cascading dependencies to occur.

Comment: `IUserStore` isn't covariant which is why you get the compiler error - does `RegisterType<IUserStore<IApplicationUser>, UserStore<IApplicationUser>>(...)` work?

Comment: Could this be of any help ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#register_inj_generic_interface Also, you should probably add a Unity tag to the question

Comment: @Lee: That was misleading error and has been removed. `IUserStore<T>` requires T to be a class.

Comment: @guillaume31: Unity tag added. The code I used for the injection constructor was from an obscure website (and worked before), but in moving to an interface-based ApplicationUser I seem to have missed a step in the type registration.

Comment: How about `RegisterType<IUserStore<>, UserStore<>>(...)` ?

Comment: @guillaume31: That is invalid syntax. `Invalid expression term '>'`

Comment: @guillaume31: The non-generic version of `RegisterType` compiles, but the problem appears to be matching the two types involved. Question updated.

Comment: I created a unit test for your first attempt and Unity resolves everything fine for me. See this gist : https://gist.github.com/infosaurus/ceae3054d263f12674ed I faked out the framework classes so they don't have as much complexity in their type signatures as the real ones. Maybe the problem lies in some of that complexity.

Comment: @guillaume31: We are tracing the dependencies, but basically one final reference needed to use the concrete `ApplicationUser` type but is in the library, which cannot reference the concrete application instance. It is one very long cascading set of dependencies that all comes down to not being able to cast the two types mentioned if the generic parameters are defined via interfaces.

Comment: The provided link above http://tect.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration is no longer available or incorrect.

Comment: @Dush: It appears the whole `tect` subdomain has been changed to `tech`.I will update the links.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I have been using

```
        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<IdentityUser>, UserStoreRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>, RoleStoreRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationRoleManager>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

the UserStoreRepository is just

```
public class UserStoreRepository : UserStore<IdentityUser>
{
    public UserStoreRepository(AuthContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

similarly

```
public class RoleStoreRepository : RoleStore<IdentityRole>
{
    public RoleStoreRepository(AuthContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

and you need to register the context of course

```
public class AuthContext: IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public AuthContext()
        : base("AuthContext")
    {

    }
}
```

for other things:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser>

 public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
```

I think your first attempt was almost right, I would try to wrap your UserStore to a different object that wraps your ApplicationUser

Comment: You have several useful things here, so +1, but the problem was caused by that blog I followed. It introduced a dependency on `ApplicationUser` on `UserManager` that should never have existed.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You can certainly add those custom objects: ApplicationUser, but once you do that, you need to tell the container everything was looking for IdentityUser now must look for ApplicationUser,

Comment: Which is where all the cascaded dependencies came from I mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the example from http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration provides a piece of code that added a dependency that should not have existed.

The solution was to change this:

```
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
}
```

to this:

```
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie))
}
```

and remove the `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method from `ApplicationUser`.

Which basically flips the call from `user(usermanager)` to `usermanager(user)` and removes the need to reference the Application user in the IApplicationUser interface!

I was then able to have the `ApplicationUser` class in one library, the interfaces in another and only specific application related class in the app.

Comment: The provided link above http://tect.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration is no longer available or incorrect.

Comment: @Dush: It appears the whole `tect` subdomain has been renamed to `tech`. I have renamed link to match.